# Have you seen this theorem before? (GCD divides, neccessary & sufficient condition)

Tags: elementary-number-theory, reference-request, polynomials, divisibility

**Conjecture**.
Let $a,b, c\in \Bbb{Z}, b \neq 0$,  The following conditions are equivalent:

(1) $d = \gcd(a,b)$ divides c.

(2) There's a polynomial in $f \in \Bbb{Z}[X,Y]$ with $c$ constant term, such that $f(a,b) = 0$.

<strike>(3) There's a polynomial $f \in \Bbb{Z}[X^{-1}, Y^{-1}, X, Y]$  with $c$ constant term such that $f(a, b) = 0$.</strike>  Thanks @ajotatxe

(3) There's a power series in $f \in \Bbb{Z}[[X,Y]]$ with $c$ constant term such that $f(a,b) \to 0$.

**Corollary.** $\gcd(a,b) = 1$ if and only if there's a polynomial (resp. series) with constant term $1$ in either of the above two rings, that vanishes at $(a,b)$.

*Motivation*: this came up studying the fact that $p$ is the first prime in a pair of twin primes iff $p(p+2)X + (p-1)!Y = 1$ has an integer solution $X,Y$.  Sub in $Z$ for $p$ and consider taking the the product $f(Z) = \prod_{n,m \in \Bbb{Z} \setminus 0} (1 - Z(Z+2)n -(Z-1)!m)$.  Then $f$ is a power series in $X = Z(Z+2), \ Y = (Z-1)!$, and $f$ has infinitely many integer solutions if and only if there are infinitely many twin prime pairs.

Thanks.

Comment: (1) if and only if (2) follows from the extended Euclidean algorithm almost immediately

Comment: @GeorgeShakan if that's true, then why haven't I ever seen it in a math text?

Comment: The point is that Euclidean algorithm gives you a linear polynomial as in (2). I do not currently see any use for having a higher degree polynomial.

Comment: This has applications to number theory.

Comment: Is condition (4) missing something? You are saying that $f(a,b)$ tends to zero when you do what?

Comment: @sdf that means the series converges to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$3$ is not equivalent to $1$. Let 
$$f=1+2X^{-1}-9Y^{-1}$$
and take $a=4$, $b=6$. We have $f(4,6)=0$ and the constant term of $c$ is $1$, but $\gcd(a,b)=2$.

Comment: Thanks.  I will remove it.  Please comment on the rest.